# Example of large solvable 3SAT problems with solution

Tags: sat

does anyone knows a link to examples of solvable 3SAT problems, with also the solution to the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a trivial solveable 3Sat instance, which is solveable in polynomial time. There are several ways to construct trivial solveable 3Sat problems:

- Use each variable exactly one times -> each variable setting is a solution
- Don't use negations -> each variable is set to true is a solution
- ...

I don't know a non trivial 3Sat example, which is big and solveable. Ones a year the [Sat Competition](http://www.satcompetition.org/) is held. You can look into the benchmarks, whether there is a 3Sat benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I did:

1. download 3 SAT examples, for for example this site:
   [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hoos/SATLIB/benchm.html](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Ehoos/SATLIB/benchm.html)
   in the download items, UF means it is satisfiable, uuf it means it is unsatisfiable.
2. Then I add these examples to https://msoos.github.io/cryptominisat_web/, which is a version of MiniSAT (SAT solver) in the browser.
3. Click the play button, and MiniSAT calculates the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get a solveable problem with one solution, first build a solution and then build a problem on it:

1. Choose any variables

   a, b, c, d, e, f
2. Choose any values for those variables (at this point, we already have the solution)

   a = true, b = false, c = true, d = true, e = false, f = false
3. Create a clause of 1, 2 or 3 literals, with at least one satisfied literal

   (¬c or **d** or e)
4. Repeat step 3 as many time you want

   (¬c or **d** or e)

   and (**a** or **¬b** or ¬d)

   and (b or e or **¬f**)

   and (**¬b** or **c** or **¬f**)

   and (**c**)

   and (**a** or **d**)

You have a solveable problem with a solution. This algorithm is exhaustive: You can get **all** the solveable problems.

**Bonus** To get an unsolveable problem:

1. Define at least 3 variables

a, b, c, d, e, f

1. Choose 3 variables among them

   b, d, f
2. Create the 8 following clauses

   (b or d or f)

   and (b or d or ¬f)

   and (b or ¬d or f)

   and (b or ¬d or ¬f)

   and (¬b or d or f)

   and (¬b or d or ¬f)

   and (¬b or ¬d or f)

   and (¬b or ¬d or ¬f)
3. Add any additional clauses

   ...

   and (¬c or d or e)

   and (a or ¬b or ¬d)

   and (b or e or ¬f)

   and (¬b or c or ¬f)

   and (c)

   and (a or d)

You have an unsolveable problem. This algorithm is **not** exhaustive: You won't get all the unsolveable problems